# Simple Amazon Cognito Registration and Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have been using Parse.com for my cloud backend and I am now looking to use AWS Mobile Hub.

Currently I am trying to create a simple login and sign-up for my app.
In Parse I could create a PFUser with a unique username and password.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this with AWS? There do not seem to be any tutorials and their documentation is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar signup and login functionality provided by Mobile Hub/Cognito at this time.